# uploadProgess() is not working

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

```
$('#formName').on('submit', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        url: "file.php",
        type: "POST",
        data: new FormData(this),
        contentType: false,
        cache: false,
        processData: false,
        beforeSend: function(){
            // do something
        },
        uploadProgress: function(event, position, total, percentComplete){
            // do something
        }
    })
    .done(function(data){
        // do something
    })
    .fail(function(data){
        // do something
    })
});
```

In above code, when actual data/statements are processed then beforeSend() & the uploadProgress() function are not working at all. Please help me understand the problem. Might the code structure is wrong or I'm missing few things within this code itsef.

Comment: To begin debugging your code, put alerts right after "$('#formName').on('submit', function(e){"  also use firebug or any other browser debugger to check till what point the flow is working..

Comment: @yeppe thank you for your response. In above code, only the uploadProgress() function is not getting triggered else it's working fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, thank you all who responded to my question, I really appreciate that. Now, after coding and testing, testing and coding and on and on and on... I came up with a solution to my own problem. And as an opportunity, I would like to share that with you all. so here its is::

1. First thing First - `uploadProgress` is not a `parameter` of `.ajax() method`, so it can't be used as I was trying to use it very first snippet.
2. Well, what if we want to to use `uploadProgress` for any kind of work to be done like upload/download or whatever. So the answer to the question is`xhr: function()` that takes care of all the `XMLHttpRequest()` within the `jquery`.

So, hope it this information may help you in any case. If

> YES

Do RATE this ANSWER :D - Have a Great Day!

Answer (score 0):

fo reference like js see[enter link description here](http://jquery.malsup.com/form/)

```js
$(function() {

    var bar = $('.bar');
    var percent = $('.percent');
    var status = $('#status');

    $('form').ajaxForm({
        beforeSend: function() {
            status.empty();
            var percentVal = '0%';
            bar.width(percentVal);
            percent.html(percentVal);
        },
        uploadProgress: function(event, position, total, percentComplete) {
            var percentVal = percentComplete + '%';
            bar.width(percentVal);
            percent.html(percentVal);
        },
        complete: function(xhr) {
            status.html(xhr.responseText);
        }
    });
});
```

```html
<form action="file-echo2.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="myfile"><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Upload File to Server">
</form>

<div class="progress">
    <div class="bar"></div >
    <div class="percent">0%</div >
</div>

<div id="status"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. But Jquery Form Plugin is not a solution for me.